# How would i print value of newLog to blank in both the conditions

Tags: javascript, jsp

```
var newLog=document.getElementById("note").value;

if(newLog==null)

elseif(newLog!=null&&newLog.equalsIgnoreCase("null"))
```

Comment: You can learn how `if/else` works here ➡ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else There is no `elseif` in JS, you need to do `else if` with a space in between. And you need to do something in at least one of those conditions, otherwise there is no point :)

Comment: My question is that how to print value of variable newLog to blank in above code

Comment: I don't understand what "print to blank" means.

Comment: Means there should to empty string

Comment: Need to print " "

Comment: "print to blank" if newLog == null, then assign newLog = '' in if or else block

Comment: can you use `newLog = newLog ? newLog : ""`

Comment: Why `jsp` is tag here?

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to print on console**

```
var newLog = document.getElementById("note").value;
// Replace "" with "Blank" if you want to print Blank
if(newLog == null || (newLog != null && newLog.equalsIgnoreCase("null")))
    console.log("");
```

**If you want to change *note* element value**

```
var newLog = document.getElementById("note").value;
// Replace "" with "Blank" if you want to print Blank
if(newLog == null || (newLog != null && newLog.equalsIgnoreCase("null")))
    document.getElementByID("note").value = ""
```